# Selenium geckodriver: profile missing: your firefox profile cannot be loaded

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

I am using geckodriver in the following code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
url = 'https://www.idealista.com/venta-viviendas/barcelona/eixample/la-dreta-de-l-eixample/?ordenado-por=fecha-publicacion-desc'
options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path='/home/kevin/Desktop/Inmosoft/geckodriver')
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
```

but everytime i try to execute i have this error:

[image]

I've tried to create another profile in firefox by using `firefox -P` following the information in this link https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-run-firefox-when-profile-missing-inaccessible.

It looks like geckodriver is a complete different instance than firefox and it does not uses the same profile, how can i bypass this error and create a profile when using geckodriver?

Answer (score 25):

I have had the same problem. In my case I am using ubuntu 22.04 and the problem is that firefox is installed by default with snap. The solution has been to uninstall firefox and install it without snap.
Here is a link to do this.

[remove snap firefox and install it as .dev](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04#:%7E:text=Installing%20Firefox%20via%20Apt%20(Not%20Snap)&text=You%20add%20the%20Mozilla%20Team,%2C%20bookmarks%2C%20and%20other%20data.)

Comment: This is the AskUbuntu solution of that post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/

Comment: Are you sure about the `${distro_codename}` in the step 4 ?

Comment: that is not a solution. this is a hack of a work-around and totally defeats the purpose of snap.

Answer (score 17):

TL/DR; Set a custom `TMPDIR` https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/2010

Find the test that is booting the geckodriver and crashing
e.g.

```bash
bundle exec rspec spec/features/sessions_spec.rb
```

When the job fails kill it via

```bash
ctrl+z # push job to background
kill %% # kill last job

# to kill all jobs do: sudo kill -9 `jobs -p -s`
```

Set a custom temporary directory via `direnv` like so:

```bash
# .envrc

export TMPDIR="$HOME/tmp/some-project"
```

> You must create the directory via `mkdir -p ~/tmp/some-project`

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the issue for me. `TMPDIR="./tmp" gradle run`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. There is no need to uninstall and reinstall firefox at all. Note that `TMPDIR` must be in the user home, setting it to `/tmp/blabla` doesn't work.

Comment: To be fair, I did kind of a bad job answering, in that I described how to solve the problem I had, rather than what the user was asking.

The solution should probably be something like: "edit your ~/.bashrc and add TMPDIR=$HOME/tmp"

Comment: Regarding Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, this is the right answer. Reinstalling the APT version of Firefox is not necessary.
For details, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1766125 and https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.31.0
Later versions of geckodriver (0.32.0) do not even require TMPDIR to be set, as they can detect the snap sandbox and place the temporary profile in another, suitable place.

Comment: They have now added a `--profile-root` argument to geckodriver: 
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/2010#issuecomment-1122739647
(For those who are running geckodriver manually)

Answer (score 11):

I solved the problem on Ubuntu 22.04 by using `geckodriver` from snap package. For example, I have directory `$HOME/bin` which is in the `$PATH`. From there I
link `firefox.geckodriver` to `$HOME/bin/geckodriver` by

```bash
$ ln -s /snap/bin/firefox.geckodriver geckodriver
```

One can found location of `firefox.geckodriver` by

```bash
$ whereis firefox.geckodriver
```

Comment: This saved me an hour! You're the best.

Comment: This is works! Simple and effective.

Comment: what is the miracle!?

Comment: This is just the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

when you run ur code make sure to set env variavle TMPDIR to local where the script user had acess to read and write :

```
import os 
os["TMPDIR"] = "path to ok location access read and write"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set all things (browser, driver, tmpdir) manually:

```py
import selenium.webdriver.firefox.service
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import utils.file_utils

# Create tmp_dir
temp_dir = "~/_tmp"
os.makedirs(temp_dir)
os.environ["TMPDIR"] = temp_dir

# Set path to firefox binary
opt = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
opt.binary_location = "/usr/bin/firefox"

# Set webdriver path
srv = selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service()
srv.path = "/home/user/prog/geckodriver/geckodriver"

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opt, service=srv)

driver.get("http://www.google.com")
print(driver.title)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just reinstall firefox and it helped.

```
sudo snap remove firefox
sudo snap install firefox
```